# How to store 3000 sensor values in TIMSCALEDB?

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

How to store data from 3000 sensor values in timescaledb ? Do i have to store timeseries data from each sensor in separate hypertable or all sensor data in single hypertable by adding "sensor id" as an identification column?

Each sensor output is time, temp 1, humidity and temp2. The number of sensors might increase significantly in future.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't add the tags for multiple (unsupported) versions. Please add only one tag for the version you are _really_ using

Comment: Hello Amal I suspect the volume of data here won't be the issue, it'll be more around how you want to use the data i.e. a database and application design decision rather than around if TimescaleDB will manage the volume (users have billions of records in hypertables in practice). Did you try the Timescale slack community for advice? I think this is going to be a challenging topic to get answered satisfactorily using StackOverflow's preferred approach as I think it needs a lot of digging in around what you need to achieve. 

Transparency: I work for Timescale.

Comment: One update to my previous comment. Searching Timescale's Slack I found this advice:

"But overall the design of one hypertable per type of sensor is pretty common/recommended."

Comment: i am confused because, in timescale documentations, several sensors and several stock market data stored within single table. but in my case number of sensors and sensor data will be huge. That's why i thinking about storing each sensor in different table. But the problem is i have limited scope to create a table for addition of sensors in future. but i can update an existing one. if i choose to go with single hypertable, and i segment table with sensor id then how to insert new sensor values to each segment @greenweeds .

Comment: reference : https://blog.timescale.com/blog/building-columnar-compression-in-a-row-oriented-database/ @greenweeds

Comment: Will you be querying by individual sensor, or across all sensors at once?

Comment: it depends on situations. sometimes we only query single sensor. sometimes more than 2000. it depends on the situations. @jjanes